# Splitting rows based on a column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfo6s.png)I have the following table output- What I have:

```
Account No     Description    Seg1    Seg2    Seg3      Budget     PeriodBalance
000-1120-00    Cash            000    1120     00       $1,000.00    $2,000.00
000-1130-00    Asset           000    1130     00       $1,500.00    $3,000.00
```

What I would like to have:

```
Account No    Description   Seg1    Seg2    Seg3    Budget      PeriodBalance
000-1120-01   Cash           000    1120    01      $500.00      $1,000.00 
000-1120-02   Cash           000    1120    02      $500.00      $1,000.00
000-1130-00   Asset          000    1130    00    $1,500.00      $3,000.00
```

Here, if the Seg2 is equal to 1120 then I would like to split it into 2 accounts suffixing the account No with 01 and 02 in place of 00 in segment 3 as shown above in the 'what i would like to hav' section.

```
declare @period int; 
declare @year int

Select @period = 12, @year = 2017

Select 
    rtrim(c.Actnumbr_1) +'-'+ rtrim(c.Actnumbr_2)+ '-'+ rtrim(c.Actnumbr_3) as ACTNUMST, 

    c.ACTDESCR, 
    c.ACTNUMBR_1, 
    c.ACTNUMBR_2, 
    c.ACTNUMBR_3,  
    sum(a.PERDBLNC) as Period_Balance,
    b.BUDGETAMT 
from GL00100 c
left outer join GL11110 a on c.ACTINDX = a.ACTINDX
Left outer join 
    (Select 
        actindx, 
        sum(budgetamt) as budgetamt 
    from GL00201  
            where BUDGETID = 'budget2017' 
            and periodid <= @period group by actindx) b 
    on c.ACTINDX = b.ACTINDX
where 
    a.PERIODID <= @period and 
    a.year1 = @year 
    --and c.ACTINDX in ('18','211') 
group by 
    c.ACTDESCR, c.ACTNUMBR_1, c.ACTNUMBR_2, c.ACTNUMBR_3, a.year1,c.ACTINDX,b.BUDGETAMT
```

Comment: Is not it odd  that no one could answer this simple question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what that second query is all about but, using this sample data:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#yourtable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #yourTable;
CREATE TABLE #yourtable
(
  [Account No]  varchar(20),
  [Description] varchar(20),
  Seg1          char(3),
  Seg2          smallint,
  Seg3          varchar(5),
  Budget        money,
  PeriodBalance money
);

INSERT #yourTable
VALUES  ('000-1120-00', 'Cash', '000', 1120, '00', $1000.00, $2000.00),
        ('000-1130-00', 'Asset','000', 1130, '00', $1500.00, $3000.00);
```

You could do this:

```
SELECT 
  [Account No]  = SUBSTRING([Account No], 1, CHARINDEX('-', [Account No], CHARINDEX('-', [Account No])+1))+ordinal,
  [Description], 
  Seg1, Seg2, 
  Seg3          = ordinal, 
  Budget        = Budget / 2, 
  PeriodBalance = PeriodBalance / 2
FROM @yourTable
CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('01'), ('02')) split(ordinal)
WHERE Seg2 = 1120
UNION ALL 
SELECT [Account No], [Description], Seg1, Seg2, Seg3, Budget, PeriodBalance
FROM @yourTable
WHERE Seg2 <> 1120;
```

... which returns:

```
Account No             Description          Seg1 Seg2   Seg3  Budget                PeriodBalance
---------------------- -------------------- ---- ------ ----- --------------------- ---------------------
000-1120-01            Cash                 000  1120   01    500.00                1000.00
000-1120-02            Cash                 000  1120   02    500.00                1000.00
000-1130-00            Asset                000  1130   00    1500.00               3000.00
```